Ffmpeg: concatenate videos and keep framerate the same
I have the following command cobbled together so far:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "\
    [0:v]trim=start=175.2:end=200.9,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
    [0:a]atrim=start=175.2:end=200.9,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; \
    [0:v]trim=start=214.3:end=324,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; \
    [0:a]atrim=start=214.3:end=324,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2]; \
    [v1][a1][v2][a2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" \
    -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" output.mp4

Extracting the clips and concatenating them into one video works fine. However, this command recodes the video to 25fps, as indicated by a warning:

[fc#0 @ 0000029e38732840] [vo0->#0:0 @ 0000029e38739b80] No information about the input framerate is available. Falling back to a default value of 25fps. Use the -r option if you want a different framerate.

I want it to keep the framerate of the original video, no matter what it is, and not drop or insert frames to change the framerate. If I use multiple input files, I want it to just use the framerate of the first one (because they’re gonna be the same anyway).
How do I achieve this?

It looks like a bug in FFmpeg version 7.0
We may fix it by adding -fps_mode passthrough argument.
According to the documentation:

passthrough (0) Each frame is passed with its timestamp from the demuxer to the muxer.


Testing:
Create synthetic 5fps video file (for testing):
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=5 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 400 input.mp4
Executing the original command with FFmpeg 5.1.2:
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=start=175.2:end=200.9,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[0:a]atrim=start=175.2:end=200.9,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];[0:v]trim=start=214.3:end=324,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];[0:a]atrim=start=214.3:end=324,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2];[v1][a1][v2][a2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" output.mp4
There is no warning message with FFmpeg 5.1.2.
Checking the framerate of output.mp4 using MediaInfo:
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 5.000 FPS


Executing the original command with FFmpeg 7.0:
./ffmpeg-7.0-full_build/bin/ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=start=175.2:end=200.9,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[0:a]atrim=start=175.2:end=200.9,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];[0:v]trim=start=214.3:end=324,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];[0:a]atrim=start=214.3:end=324,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2];[v1][a1][v2][a2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" output.mp4
There is a warning message "No information about the input framerate is available".
Checking the framerate of output.mp4 using MediaInfo:
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS

FFmpeg 7.0 changed the framerate to 25 fps.

Executing the updated (with -fps_mode passthrough) command with FFmpeg 7.0:
./ffmpeg-7.0-full_build/bin/ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -fps_mode passthrough -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=start=175.2:end=200.9,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[0:a]atrim=start=175.2:end=200.9,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];[0:v]trim=start=214.3:end=324,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];[0:a]atrim=start=214.3:end=324,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2];[v1][a1][v2][a2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" output.mp4
There is a new warning message: "MB rate (84000000) > level limit (16711680)" (another bug?).
Checking the framerate of output.mp4 using MediaInfo:
Format profile                           : High@L6.2
...
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 5.000 FPS

Most video players ignore the "Level", but if level 6.2 is problematic, try using other version of FFmpeg.

Did not expect that it would be an actual bug. Thank you so much for your investigation.

I believe the filter setpts=PTS-STARTPTS is the one to blame.
Example:
ffmpeg \
    -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "\
    [0:v]scale=640x360,trim=start=13:end=14,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];\
    [0:a]atrim=start=13:end=14,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];\
    [0:v]scale=640x360,trim=start=16:end=17,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];\
    [0:a]atrim=start=16:end=17,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2];\
    [v1][a1][v2][a2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" \
    -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" \
    -c:v:0 libsvtav1 output1.mp4

This will get you

Svt[error]: Instance 1: The maximum allowed frame rate is 240 fps

Telling us the encoder receives no fps/pts info. Why is it lost?
Now if you omit all those setpts=PTS-STARTPTS and asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS, the encoder will work, but the result is a mess, not what you want.
There is a workaround:
ffmpeg \
    -ss 13 -t 1 -i input.mp4 \
    -ss 16 -t 1 -i input.mp4 \
    -filter_complex "\
    [0:v:0]scale=640x360[v1];\
    [0:a:0]aresample=async=1[a1];\
    [1:v:0]scale=640x360[v2];\
    [1:a:0]aresample=async=1[a2];\
    [v1][a1][v2][a2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" \
    -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" \
    -c:v:0 libsvtav1 output2.mp4

double your input, use -ss and -t to trim your input instead
-ss 13 tells ffmpeg to read input starting at 00:00:13.
-t 1 tells ffmpeg this input duration is one sec.
The "-fps_mode passthrough" with libx264, giving a warning, does work on my machine, but libsvtav1 does not.
And avoiding using filter will save a lot of time and memory.
